# iOS iPhone app - iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ipad, iphone

The iPhone app works really well on the regular iPhones

The iPas app works really well on iPads

But the 6 plus fills a strange niche - in vertical mode it works much like any other iPhone, but in horizontal orientation it's more akin to an iPad mini

As such the iPhone app feels a bit 'wrong' on the 6 plus. It doesn't utilise the extra space available in the horizontal view - when many apps use a two column layout much like the iPad. I believe there's a facility for doing this within existing iOS development tools, would it be possible for us to start using it?

Comment: We originally considered making the feed on the iPhone 6+ match more closely to the feed on the iPad (no horizontal scrolling) but ended up changing our minds last second because when a 6+ and a 6 were next to each other running the app it just felt too different. We might change our mind again here.